# PyGtk equivalent of gdk_window_ensure_native?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Is there an equivalent to gdk_window_ensure_native in PyGtk? I need it to unbreak drawing OpenGl to widget in Gtk >= 2.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
>>> import gtk
>>> w = gtk.Window()
>>> w.show_all()
>>> gw = w.get_window()
>>> gw
<gtk.gdk.Window object at 0xa31e824 (GdkWindow at 0xa38ea28)>
>>> gw.ensure_native()
True
>>> gw.has_native()
True
```

Alternatively, You may try setting environmental variable `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1`

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `gtk.gdk.Window` of a widget/window using [`gtk.Widget.get_window()`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-window), and then use undocumented `gtk.gdk.Window.ensure_native()`, e.g.: `my_widget.get_window().ensure_native()`. Works at least with `pygtk2-2.17.0` I have available at hand.